# Use-cases for objects in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, oop, object, data-modeling

Recently I discoverd that you can store instances of defined types within tables. Since 9th version of Oracle database it gives you ability to all object paradigm features like encapsulation, inheritance and polimorphism.

```
CREATE TYPE t_some_type AS OBJECT ();
CREATE TABLE some_objs OF t_some_type;
```

For me it's kind of adopt technique oop which became very popular last years and I doubt  about some practical use-cases.

- Is there any particular reason to declare and store objects instead of tables?
- Do you have any particular project involving applying objects in Oracle database?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the documentation that Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjint.htm#i457396) provides, there are at least three advantages in using objects in the database:

- Objects Can Encapsulate Operations Along with Data
- Objects Are Efficient
- Objects Can Represent Part-Whole Relationships

However, in my eyes object often complicate things and are not commonly used in applications. I have not worked with many applications that use objects (types) extensively. They may make sense for particular use-cases, but generally I would advise against using them and instead focus on using a proper ORM framework. **Note that this is just my personal opinion. YMMV.**